# Syntax for REST API to have bold formatted and multiple lines in product description

Tags: wp-api

My description in the "Edit Product" GUI visual looks like:

Description

**Features :**

Feature 1

Feature 2

I use the rest API to dump out the description and it looks like this:

```
"description":"<p>Description<\/p>\n<p><strong>Features :<\/strong><\/p>\n<p>Feature 1<\/p>\n<p>Feature 2<\/p>\n"
```

However, if I put that description into json, I get:

```
Array ( [code] => woocommerce_rest_cannot_view [message] => Sorry, you cannot view this resource. [data] => Array ( [status] => 401 ) )
```

it looks like I can't a have multiple `<\/p\>` in the json, but I need them to get the downstream formatting to work.

Comment: Playing around with it some more, it is the <strong> before the Features : that is the issue that is causing the 401 status.

Comment: 401 is the HTTP code for Forbidden, it means you don't have the permission to view that resource from the client. Has nothing to do with HTML in the description. I can see this is a WooCommerce endpoint, so you should refer to WooCommerce support/documentation for handling authentication with WooCommerce endpoints.

Comment: Yes, I see 401 is a permission problem, but if I remove the <strong> statement, it works fine, hence my line of reasoning it is a syntax issue.

Comment: This input json:"<br />\nFeatures :<br />\n" gives me the following back from the product when I dump out the description: <br \/>\n<strong>Features :<\/strong><br \/>\n The last step is to add Feature 2 as only Feature1 is being accepted (no error messages). Sorry I haven't figured out how to do the formatting of this question.

Comment: That last comment isn't correct. The API is not giving an error, but instead not taking the json data. It is showing me what is stored rather than what I gave it to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Through more experimentation, I found the culprit-

This does not work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
```

This does work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

So it was the processing of the data in $data through curl which was causing the permission problem.